# HTTP error 400 when fetching BirdEye API with ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to retrieve some customer review data using an API from BirdEye.  This is for a WP site.  It comes in a cUrl format, but I want to do it with Javascript.  I tested it out in Postman and was able to get the data, but can't get it to work in my actual project.  I keep getting a 400 (bad request) error.  Here is my code :

```
$(window).load(() => {
    let data = {
      fromDate: "01/01/2020",
      toDate: "01/01/2021",
      sources: ["google", "citysearch"],
      ratings: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0],
    };
    let url =
      "https://api.birdeye.com/resources/v1/review/businessId/***************?sindex=0&count=25&api_key=******************************";
    $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: url,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
      },
      data: data,
      dataType: "json",
    })
      .done((data) => {
        console.log(data);
      })
      .fail(() => {
        console.log("error");
      });
  });
});
```

I'm not really sure where to go from here.  Is this possible to do?

Comment: It should be `data: JSON.stringify(data)`

Comment: You don't want curl. You want ajax. It's either curl or ajax. They are the same thingish.

Comment: You don't need to provide the `Accept:` header. `$.ajax` sets that automatically based on the `dataType:` option.

Comment: Be sure your API endpoint allows JS requests from your domain. Otherwise Access-Control-Origin will block you.

Comment: You can try an online curl to Ajax converter: https://reqbin.com/req/javascript/c-wyuctivp/convert-curl-to-javascript

Comment: Send your data over, build your cURL on the Server, do what you need to on the Server, then send back to the Client.

Comment: If you got it to work in Postman, you can also just click the button that gives you the code snippet and pick the ajax option.

Comment: That was it @Barmar!  Thank you!